# Joining two string arrays, line by line in matlab without using a for loop through the array

Tags: matlab

I know this is simple. I just can't remember how to do this!

What I have:

```
>> filenames

filenames = 

    '0F06EB0A338A35CDBD33356A470D5052'
    '75168DAA9A225EF6F79DDA5014CA69FD'
    'DAEE5EE3E65584655CE208F15D1F6F43'
    'EF026066C8BAB5D32F9B67872C69451D'
```

What I want:

```
>> varnames

varnames = 

    'x0F06EB0A338A35CDBD33356A470D5052'
    'x75168DAA9A225EF6F79DDA5014CA69FD'
    'xDAEE5EE3E65584655CE208F15D1F6F43'
    'xEF026066C8BAB5D32F9B67872C69451D'
```

(I know about `genvarnames` but that's not what I'm going to use for this, since I need `x` in front of all of them).

What I've tried so far

```
>> ['x' filenames{1}]

ans =

x0F06EB0A338A35CDBD33356A470D5052
```

Great success! Now I just need to generalize this to the whole thing. However, I'm not going to use a for-loop, since I'm not an ogre.

Let's try this:

```
>> ['x' filenames{:}]

ans =

x0F06EB0A338A35CDBD33356A470D505275168DAA9A225EF6F79DDA5014CA69FDDAEE5EE3E65584655CE208F15D1F6F43EF026066C8BAB5D32F9B67872C69451D
```

Weeeell, almost, maybe `repmat` can help! Since obviously:

```
>> repmat('x', 4, 1)

ans =

x
x
x
x
```

That's all I need to get this working, right??

```
>> varnames= [repmat('x', 4, 1) filenames{:}]
??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

Wrong. Perhaps it's as simple as:

```
>> varnames= [repmat('x', 4, 1) filenames(:)]
??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

What if I just remove them alltogether...?

```
>> varnames= [repmat('x', 4, 1) filenames]
??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

... Let's just pepper `{}` all over this

```
>> varnames= {repmat('x', 4, 1) filenames{:}}

varnames = 

  Columns 1 through 4

    [4x1 char]    [1x32 char]    [1x32 char]    [1x32 char]

  Column 5

    [1x32 char]
```

... crap.

Well I'm out of ideas, and I won't bother you with more of my failed attempts. 
I refuse to believe that a for loop is the only way to do this!

Comment: `strcat('x',filenames)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html

"Concatenate strings horizontally"

```
strcat('x',StringMatrix)
```

Test:

```
>> SA2
SA2 = 
    'four'    'five'    'six'
>> strcat('x',SA2)
ans = 
    'xfour'    'xfive'    'xsix'
```

Comment: Gdammit I knew it was too simple for my stupid brain.